# Should the avatar of the person that edited a question be displayed?

Tags: feature-request, design

This question is inspired by a mistake that I did here [How to know the number of pages in a PDF file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8316/the-number-of-pages-contained-in-a-document-called-by-includegraphics) (see the comments)

I generally find that the editor's avatar and name tend to distract. Should the details of the editor be displayed in smaller letters and with no avatar?

Comment: I have to say that I like it as is.